# non-increasing partitions of integer number in R

Tags: r

How to write a function in r that given an integer n  computes all non-increasing partitions of n.

```
Example:

For n=3,

1 1 1

2 1

3

 

For n=4,

1 1 1 1

2 2

2 1 1

3 1

4
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SO is a problem solving tool, not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the question. Just posting my answer.

```
#install.packages("partitions")
library(partitions)

partition <- function(n){
  x<- t(parts(n))
  
  x[nrow(x):1,]
  
  
}
partition(3)
partition(4)
```